# How does the mlrMBO package optimize hyperparameters when no objective function is specified?

Tags: r, hyperparameters, mlr

I am still very new to the mlrMBO package and hyperparameter tuning in general, so I apologize for the ignorance here. Previously I was using the makeTuneControlGrid() function for grid search hyperparameter tuning for random forest and decision tree classification models, and then I was introduced to the mlrMBO package, and have used nearly the same code that I used for grid search, only used the makeTuneControlMBO() function instead. The performance metrics greatly improved from the grid search, but I am not understanding how the functions in this package are searching differently from grid search for optimal hyperparameter combinations, when I did not yet specify an objective function. My understanding from what I have read is that I need to make an objective function to optimize, so if this objective function is never created, how is the package searching hyperparameters if it is not using grid search? Is it optimizing a default objective function that is built into the package?

Here is my code:

```
task <- makeClassifTask(data = training_data, target = 'DEATH_EVENT', id = 'Death', positive = 1)
View(task)
# Configure learners with probability type
learner2 <- makeLearner('classif.randomForest', predict.type = 'prob')  # Random Forest learner
View(learner2)
learner3 <- makeLearner('classif.kknn', predict.type = 'prob')          # kNN learner

library(mlrMBO)

getParamSet("classif.randomForest")

ps2 <- makeParamSet(
  makeDiscreteParam('mtry', values = seq(1,5, by = 1))
  
  ,
  makeDiscreteParam('ntree', values = seq(450,600, by = 50)),
  
  makeDiscreteParam('nodesize', values = seq(7,14, by = 1))
  
)

#creates a control object for MBO optimization
ctrl = makeTuneControlMBO(mbo.control=mlrMBO::makeMBOControl())

rdesc = makeResampleDesc("CV", iters = 5L)
tuned_params <- tuneParams(learner = learner2, 
                           task = task, 
                           control = ctrl, 
                           par.set = ps2, 
                           resampling = rdesc, 
                           measures=list(tpr,auc, fnr, mmce, tnr, setAggregation(tpr, test.sd)), show.info=T)
tuned_params$x
tuned_params$y
tuned_params$mbo.result
```

Comment: Can you show us your code please?

Comment: Okay I attached the code. I'm just mainly wondering how the Bayesian optimization is working in this code and specifically how to find the objective and surrogate functions.

Comment: That's why I asked for the code -- your objective function is what you give in `measures` to `tuneParams` and the surrogate model is the default (in this case a random forest as you specify only discrete parameters (which look like they should really be numeric)).

Comment: Okay so will things change if I change the parameters to numeric? Currently my code seems to work and predicts fairly well. So as far as I understand my objective function is optimizing for true positive rate, I guess I am still confused conceptually about how the surrogate function works in this case because I read that Bayesian optimization works by creating a probability distribution of objective function values (in this case true positive rate?) given hyperparameter values. Is it creating a probability distribution here or is there a way to obtain that? Sorry, still very inexperienced

Comment: Sounds like you should read up on the background, e.g. [chapter 1 of the AutoML book](https://www.automl.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/AutoML_Book_Chapter1.pdf).